# How to set startActivityForResult from an adapter and get the result in a viewPager fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter, startactivityforresult

I know there are several related topics but I have tried them all and nothing happens. I have a "MainActivity" class that contains a fragment called "HomeFragment" which this fragment contains a viewPager with two fragments one of them called "ListFragment". By setting up an adapter named as "ListAdapter" an onClick method for each items works fine, the problem is when I set:

```
                intentRequestDetails.putExtra(KEY_POSITION, position);
                intentRequestDetails.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intentRequestDetails, 2);
```

to onItemClick in adapter,
I do not know how to get result in "ListFragment".
I pass "getActivity()" to adapter and ListFragment but non of them worked!
Please help me with this to get result in "ListFragment"

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 2) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            int position = data.getIntExtra("position", -1);
            userRequestsViewModel.getResult().remove(position);
            viewHolder.rView.getAdapter().notifyItemRemoved(position);
            viewHolder.rView.getAdapter().notifyItemRangeChanged(position, viewHolder.rView.getAdapter().getItemCount());

        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
```

**What I need**
is what to pass from fragment to adapter as context? where and how to override the onActivityResult and if there is anything else that i missed?

- The onActivityResult in ListFragment does not triggered since the startActivityForResult is being called from ListAdapter! How should I handle this?
- How to get adapter and ListFragment in MainActivity if its a chance to update the list?

Comment: If you have overridden the method `onActivityResult` in your Activity, make sure you have not missed the call to `super.onActivityResult`

Comment: No when I tried that again nothing happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending hours of research I finally solve this problem as follow:
As I have two nested fragments as child and parent in a one activity and I design to take action on each item click on the recyclerView items and going to another activity to get the result back and refreshing the list I added this code in MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(1);
    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

which select the targeted fragment (parentFragment) to pass data to, and then in that parentFragment I add this method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Fragment fragment = getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(1);
    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

to send onActivityResult to the child fragment. After all in the child fragment:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == 2){
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            int position = data.getIntExtra("position", -1);
            userRequestsViewModel.getResult().remove(position);
            viewHolder.rView.getAdapter().notifyItemRemoved(position);
            viewHolder.rView.getAdapter().notifyItemRangeChanged(position, viewHolder.rView.getAdapter().getItemCount());
        }
    }
}
```

to refresh the recyclerView adapter and notify it that an item has been removed! Another important point is that in adapter I just did this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), SecondActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra(KEY_POSITION, position);
                ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

and remove this line of code:

```
intentRequestDetails.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

and of course I passed the context of activity from fragment to adapter: simply

```
getContext()
```

I hope this works for you too if you deal with such a problem one day

Answer (score 0):

In addition to override `onActivityResult` in fragment, you also need override it in activity class:

```
@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById("yourFragment"); 
    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
}
```

and in fragment:

```
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   //do something
  }
```

Comment: I did it but still does not work, I have a fragment with two child and a MainActivity, I tried all possibilities!